# Do we nee to login to our account to get an authorization code as first step towards creation of token in docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

If URI for getting authorization code is : https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback/
do I need to login to get the authization code.
Is there another way to get token in production environment?
Is there an api available for login in docusign?

Comment: Answered below. If it helped you out, be sure to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, I would strongly suggest [reading this guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication) on DocuSign authentication.

As to whether you need to have each and every user login to DocuSign, the answer is no. If you're developing a service integration, you can use the JWT grant flow to interact directly with DocuSign w/o having to authenticate each individual user.